# liquibase not doing any updates on SQL Server databse but log says everything is successful

Tags: sql-server, maven, liquibase

I am trying to use Liquibase to deploy SQL DML and DDL to SQL server database. I am invoking liquibase through maven. the below output from maven shows that the changeset is applied. But when i connect to SQL server Database from SSMS I don't see the DATABASECHANGELOG or DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table in the DB. The Id I am using only has access to one DB dbname. So I am not sure what's going on

jdbc driver mssql-jdbc version 8.4.1.jre8 liquibase version 4.2.2

> [INFO] Output SQL Migration File:
> /opt/jenkins/7cb92e15/workspace/Clinical/database/sql/target/liquibase/migrate.sql
> [INFO] Executing on Database:
> jdbc:sqlserver://Sername\DEV;databasename=dbname [INFO] Successfully
> acquired change log lock [INFO] Configured classpath location
> file:/opt/jenkins/7cb92e15/workspace/Clinical/database/sql/target/classes
> does not exist [INFO] Configured classpath location
> file:/opt/jenkins/7cb92e15/workspace/Clinical/database/sql/target/classes
> does not exist [INFO] Configured classpath location
> file:/opt/jenkins/7cb92e15/workspace/Clinical/database/sql/target/test-classes
> does not exist [INFO] Configured classpath location
> file:/opt/jenkins/7cb92e15/workspace/Clinical/database/sql/target/classes
> does not exist [INFO] Creating database history table with name:
> DATABASECHANGELOG [INFO] Custom SQL executed [INFO] ChangeSet
> test/test1.sql::raw::includeAll ran successfully in 94ms [INFO]
> ChangeSet ./liquibase.xml::1::dev2 ran successfully in 93ms [INFO]
> Successfully released change log lock [INFO]
>
> ---

Comment: Does `sername` on the Jenkins machine resolve to the same IP address as it does on your own machine?

Comment: I got different ip address for the db server when I did nslookup from my local and my jenkins server. But the non-authoritative answer for nslookup returns same ipaddress from my local and jenkins server. Is this an issue? Are there any questions I should ask my serverteam?

Comment: Using the IP address your Jenkins machine resolves try connecting SSMS to ip-address\DEV with the credentials and see if the DATABASECHANGELOG table exists there. If it does then you can be certain there are (at least) two different servers on your network linked to the name `sername`, then ask your server team what's going on and why they are different machines.

Comment: I am not able to connect using either ipaddress returned. I am only able to connect using the ipaddress that is returned by non-authoritative answer

Comment: I checked with my DB admin and enabled trace on DB. Liquibase is trying to run a select statement on the DATABASECHANGELOG without creating it and throwing a object not found error. I tried running liquibase against new database and see the same issue

Comment: Can you include your pom.xml with the relevant liquibase configs?

Comment: updating the dbname as per this seems to resolve the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019803/liquibases-sqlfile-command-being-ignored-for-sql-server